# WPF to jpg/gif/png/svg

Tags: c#, wpf, image, jpeg

Is there any programmatic way to convert a WPF controls (FrameworkElement) with drawings to an image of jpg/png/gif/svg format?

Comment: You could look at using the print functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [WPF Screenshot JPG from UIElement with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977385/wpf-screenshot-jpg-from-uielement-with-c)